# How to get the WKWebView resource files

Tags: swift, local-storage, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

How to access WKWebView asset folder. 
I want to get one image form WKWebView asset folder. When web is loaded. Is it possible to access asset folder of WKWebView like accessing cookies. I tried WKWebsiteDataStore and NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains. But I could not located the asset of WKWebView local folder in my application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no apple API that contains the cookies data in local or file folder.

You should go through first [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview).

Comment: We will get cookies from  webView.getCookies(for: webView.url?.host) { data in